# Not able to Add CONNECTION Timeout to a CXF WebService with HttpConduit

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

The following code is what i have used to add Connection and Receive `timeout` to my `CXF` Web Service,Receive timeout works fine but Connection `timeout` does not and i think i have a clue why ,the service tries to connect at line1 but the code for setting `timeout` follows the code,as it always gets stuck at line1 ,how will it ever set a `timeout` at line2.Please share if there is any other way to set the timeout.

```
CalculatorService cal = new CalculatorService(); //line1
Calculator port= cal.getCalculatorPort();
Client cl = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)cl.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(5000); //line2
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(4000);

http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
port.add(1, 2);
```

Comment: I cannot maintain a local wsdl because the URL is not static.

Comment: The connection to the server will be performed in the last line, so probably you have a bug in the constructor of the service as says MachineLearning. Please, post the code of `new CalculatorService` to view how to fix it

Comment: @pedrofb if the wsdl is not local, the initialization in the first line opens a connection to the server to get the remote wsdl document